# What are these words?

Tags: word, wordplay

1. Which word means "to push hard", and if it is written backwards it
   means "to spoil"?
2. A synonym of this word is "stalemate", and if it is written backwards a
   synonym of the transformed word is "department". Which word?
3. A synonym of this word is "deviate", and if it is written backwards a
   synonym of the transformed word is "method". Which word?

Comment: These are three different words?

Comment: @skv, yes three different words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The answer is

> **Mar**
>  Ram is to push hard, mar is to spoil.

2. The answer is

> **Draw**
>  The synonym of stalemate is "draw", the anagram is "ward" and ward is a synonym for department

3. The answer is:

> **Part**
>  It's the only synonym for deviate I can think of that makes a real word when reversed, but "trap" doesn't really mean method.
>  However, I misread a bit, thanks @d'alar'cop
>  "a synonym of "trap" is "stratagem" which is also a "method"."

Comment: a synonym of "trap" is "stratagem" which is also a "method". you win. (see 3 again - it's a synonym of the reverse that you need to mean "method ")

Answer (score 3):

A previous answer gave apparently-correct results for parts 1 and 2, but missed out on part 3, which is:

> **[yaw](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yaw#Verb)**, “To swerve off course to port or starboard”,  “To steer badly, zigzagging back and forth across the intended course” etc., thus analogous to *deviate*;  and   **[way](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/way#Noun)**, “A method or manner of doing something”, thus analogous to *method*.